# Can I make Django's {% url %} template tag ignore None when passed as a parameter, so making the parameter optional?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a site with listings, that I am writing filters for to segment the listings.
So I could have:

```
/listings/furniture/
/listings/london/
/listings/free/
```

I can also chain these together, eg:

```
/listings/free/furniture/
/listings/free/furniture/london/
```

When building links for these filters, I want to leave out the filter if it's set to a default (eg. `everywhere` or `everything`.  So rather than saying eg:

```
/listings/free/everything/everywhere/
```

I would want to just say:

```
/listings/free/
```

I have an `urls.py` configuration as follows:

```
url(r'^listings/(?P<param1>[\w-]+)/$', 'main.web.listings'),
url(r'^listings/(?P<param1>[\w-]+)/(?P<param2>[\w-]+)/$', 'main.web.listings'),
url(r'^listings/(?P<param1>[\w-]+)/(?P<param2>[\w-]+)/(?P<param3>[\w-]+)/$', 'main.web.listings'),
```

And when I'm building the url for the links in a template I use code like:

```
{% url 'main.web.listings' "free" category_selected.slug location_selected.slug %}
```

This would link using the currently selected category and location, and change the page to show only "free" items.

So, to the question:  In the template, I can sometimes have a category_selected.slug and sometimes not, and I would like the `{% url ... %}` tag to ignore a parameter when it is set to `None`.  By default, however, at the moment it returns something like:

```
/listings/free/None/None/
```

I would like, in this situation, to return:

```
/listings/free/
```

Is there a way around this, or a better way to do it that I'm missing?

Comment: I am stuck at the exact same situation. Anyone has a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% url 'main.web.listings' param1="free" param2=category_selected.slug param3=location_selected.slug %}
```

Comment: This does the same as my code: `{% url 'main.web.listings' "free" category_selected.slug location_selected.slug %}`.  If eg. `category_selected.slug = None` and `location_selected.slug = None` then I get:
`/listings/free/None/None/`
I'm after:
`/liatings/free/`

Answer (score 0):

I am also stuck at something similar to this. I found a solution for my case. I am using Django 2.2 so I use `path()` instead:
`urls.py`

```
path('item/<int:item_id>/', views.show_item, name='show_item'),
path('item/<int:item_id>/<slug:slug>/', views.show_item, name='show_item'),
```

`views.py`

```
def show_item(request, item_id, slug=None):
```

`show_item.html`

```
<a href="{% url 'show_item' item_id=item.id %}{% if not item.slug is None %}{{ item.slug }}/{% endif %}">{{ item.name }}</a>
```

In your case, the answer might look like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'main.web.listings' "free" %}{% if not category_selected.slug is None %}{{ category_selected.slug }}/{% endif %}{% if not location_selected.slug is None %}{{ location_selected.slug }}/{% endif %}">Back to free item listings</a>
```